# JSF Datatable Alingnement

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, jsf-2

I have List of objects from MyClassForDatatable class, where

```
public class MyClassForDatatable
    public String PropertyA
    public String PropertyB
    public String PropertyC
    public String PropertyD
    //getters and setters
    ...
```

Is it possible to create a Datatable like:

[image: Datatable Example Image]

instead of the usual way:

[image: Datatable Example Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want a `colspan`? This is not supported in the standard JSF component library.

Either use plain vanilla HTML

```xml
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
    </tr>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
        <tr>
            <td>#{item.propertyA}</td>
            <td>#{item.propertyB}</td>
            <td>#{item.propertyC}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">#{item.propertyD}</td>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

Or head to a 3rd party component library which offers colspans like that. RichFaces for example, has a [`<rich:columnGroup>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_columnGroup.html) which should do what you want.